# Android: Upload html file to http server

Tags: php, android, html, http, upload

I am currently trying to upload a HTML file to my lamp server using android.
I really can't figure out how to get the file to upload to the server. What i'm doing is: writing a HTML file programmatically and then uploading it to the web-server.
I know it's possible.

I've already made a start, writing the file. I also have an upload script on my server:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

I've read all these tutorials on how to do it, but I simply don't get it.

Comment: What about your Android Java code?

Comment: There's no java code, I simply can't find the right code, The example i found online dooesn't work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018883/android-file-upload) and i can't write my own

Comment: in your android code for upload, did you make sure it is in multipart entity when uploading the HTML file?

Comment: If you use a LAMP server i think that it is not public you have configured right the comunnication? 
try first to post a string, if it work then you can try with file.

Comment: just in case you can check this out just to know how to:

https://github.com/kahelnadiablo/android_uploader

Comment: Please update your question with the HTML form to allow client to upload a file. I think the form may have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as android code:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile", sourceFileUri);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                Log.e("uploadFile", "File Uploaded.");
                // Congrats!
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```